# How come this county has both Muslim and Christian holdings?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I am neighbouring the Kingdom of Navarra. Some of their holdings have mixed ownership. As you can see in this screenshot, the castle belongs to Navarra, while the temple and the city belongs to the Emirate of Galicia.

[image]

If you hover over the Emirate of Galicia, the tooltip says:

> **De Jure: Emirate of Galicia**.
>   The *County of Santiago* is traditionally considered part of the *Emirate
>   of Galicia*. Emir Rasiq of Portucale is the current duke, who will
>   strive to regain actual control of Santiago.

This is not the only example – many holdings in the Iberian peninsula have mixed ownership. As you can imagine, this makes it confusing to create an overview over allies and enemies in the region.

How is this possible? Is it a bug? I am playing an older version of the game – 2.0.4.

Comment: BTW, the quoted text about de jure emirate has nothing to do with the question. That says that the county of Santiago is [de jure](http://www.ckiiwiki.com/De_jure) part of the Emirate of Galicia, even if it isn't part of it de facto.

Comment: @svick Yes, I am aware, but I included it on the off-chance that it was relevant. The interesting part was the part where it says that the duchy exists (as an Emirate), although the Emir holds no titles in the region (which I admit is not clear from the material). The King of Navarra has simply not decided to usurp the title.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a bug. Barony level holdings can be owned by anyone- not necessarily someone who swears fealty to the holder of that county. Baronies held other realms are indicated by a small symbol for that realm appearing in the county.

There are several ways this can happen- usually involving taking the county while the holdings are occupied by someone else. Without knowing more about the situation I can't say for sure what happened.

If there are holdings in your counties which do not swear fealty to you or your vassals, you can use the County Claim casus belli to claim them- this is similar to a De Jure claim but on a smaller scale.